# Splitting strings in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, split, strsplit

Does anyone know how to split my address columns. I would like to divide it into three new columns, seperated by it's commas.
For example *1808  FOX CHASE DR, GOODLETTSVILLE, TN* is divided into

- 1808 FOX CHASE DR
- GOODLETTSVILLE
- TN

So far I've tried

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(OwnerAddress, 1, INSTR(OwnerAddress, ',')-1) as col1,
SUBSTRING(OwnerAddress, INSTR(OwnerAddress, ',')+1) as col2  
FROM housing_data;
```

Although I cannot create the third column with the state abbreviation.

Thanks for any input

Comment: Address data is notoriously difficult to algorithmically parse if you haven’t done so upfront. There are way too many edge cases to do this in SQL - consider using a trained ML algorithm like `libpostal` to perform this for you - it’ll perform at a much higher accuracy than any other method you may be considering. Was the data controlled on the way in? Can you guarantee 100% this data is always structured in the same manner? Please read [Falsehoods programmers believe about addresses](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/) to scratch the surface…

Comment: For starters, you should look to rectify your data model to capture these distinct data points up front to make your life a hell of a lot easier.

Comment: @esqew thank you for you suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally much cleaner to do any sort of string processing in the target library.  That said, if you must, you can make liberal use of `SUBSTRING` and `INSTR` to find each comma and split the strings:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(OwnerAddress, 1, INSTR(OwnerAddress, ',') - 1) as col1,
    SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(OwnerAddress, INSTR(OwnerAddress, ',') + 1), 1, INSTR(SUBSTRING(OwnerAddress, INSTR(OwnerAddress, ',') + 1), ',') - 1) as col2,
    SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(OwnerAddress, INSTR(OwnerAddress, ',') + 1), INSTR(SUBSTRING(OwnerAddress, INSTR(OwnerAddress, ',') + 1), ',') + 1) as col3
FROM housing_data;
```

Comment: This is a rather shortsighted suggestion for parsing unstructured address data - what if the address contains a second street address line? For example, something like `1808 FOX CHASE DR, APARTMENT 101, GOODLETTSVILLE, TN`? What if the address contains an addressee, i.e. `BUSINESS ABC, 1808 FOX CHASE DR, GOODLETTSVILLE, TN`? Your proposal fails to account for many of the classic edge cases documented on [Falsehoods programmers believe about addresses](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion as well. Bit of overkill for what should be a simple problem. But, here, you'd be able to split as many commas as are provided.

```
CREATE TABLE addresses AS
SELECT '1808 FOX CHASE DR, GOODLETTSVILLE, TN' AS address; 


WITH RECURSIVE cte (address, remaining_address) AS (
        SELECT CASE WHEN a.address LIKE '%, %'
                    THEN SUBSTRING(a.address, 1, INSTR(a.address, ', ')-1)
                    ELSE a.address
                    END AS address
             , SUBSTRING( SUBSTRING(a.address, INSTR(a.address, ', ')+1), 1) AS remaining_address
        FROM addresses AS a
    UNION ALL
        SELECT CASE WHEN c.remaining_address LIKE '%, %' 
                    THEN SUBSTRING(c.remaining_address, 1, INSTR(c.remaining_address, ', ')-1) 
                    ELSE c.remaining_address END AS address
             , CASE WHEN c.remaining_address LIKE '%, %' 
                    THEN SUBSTRING( SUBSTRING(c.remaining_address, INSTR(c.remaining_address, ', ')+1), 1)
                    END AS remaining_address
        FROM cte c
        WHERE c.address <> ''
            AND c.address IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY address DESC) AS address_id
     , address
FROM cte
WHERE address <> ''
    AND address IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY address;
```

You'd have to go a little further to fix it up into columns, but it's doable, and you can add logic to handle potential extra commas.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS addresses;

CREATE TABLE addresses AS
SELECT '1808 FOX CHASE DR, APT.1, SUBUNIT 10, GOODLETTSVILLE, TN' AS address; 


WITH RECURSIVE cte (address, city, state, remaining_address) AS (
        SELECT CASE WHEN a.address LIKE '%, %'
                    THEN SUBSTRING(a.address, 1, INSTR(a.address, ', ')-1)
                    ELSE a.address
                    END AS address 
             , NULL AS city
             , NULL AS state
             , SUBSTRING( SUBSTRING(a.address, INSTR(a.address, ', ')+1), 1) AS remaining_address
        FROM addresses AS a
    UNION ALL
        SELECT CASE WHEN c.remaining_address LIKE '%, %, %' 
                    THEN c.address || ', ' || SUBSTRING(c.remaining_address, 1, INSTR(c.remaining_address, ', ')-1)  
                    ELSE c.address END AS address
             , CASE WHEN c.city IS NOT NULL
                    THEN c.city
                    WHEN c.remaining_address LIKE '%, %, %'
                    THEN NULL
                    WHEN c.remaining_address LIKE '%, %'
                    THEN SUBSTRING(c.remaining_address, 1, INSTR(c.remaining_address, ', ')-1) 
                    ELSE c.remaining_address END AS city
             , CASE WHEN c.remaining_address NOT LIKE '%, %' THEN c.remaining_address END AS state
             , CASE WHEN c.remaining_address LIKE '%, %' 
                    THEN SUBSTRING( SUBSTRING(c.remaining_address, INSTR(c.remaining_address, ', ')+1), 1)
                    END AS remaining_address
        FROM cte c
        WHERE c.state IS NULL
)
SELECT address, city, state
FROM cte
WHERE state IS NOT NULL
```

Output:

[image: column output]